# Returning a value from an SQL Method

Tags: php, sql, class, include, extends

]i'm completely out of idea's as to why the code below does not return the value. I have 2 sql tables that related to one another. Within a class i have the following method, and within the scope of that method all is well. The var dump shows the correct data. The following code is stated in class.php.

```
public function getId($username, $password) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT person_id FROM user WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $id = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $id = $id[0];
    }
    ELSE {
        echo "Failed to retreive person_id";
    }
    var_dump($id);
    return $id[0];
}
```

However when i return that value to the showinfo.php which is the main document and state the following:

```
$user_id = $id[0];
var_dump($user_id);
```

Then the var dump echoes "NULL". And I need it for the follwing method which is also in class.php.

```
public function showInfo($user_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r  ($row, true)."</pre>";
    }
}
```

Could anybody be so kind as to show me ways to get this done?
Many thanks in advance for your time and effort in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to access the field with the index `[0]` twice.

Maybe try to return just $id and then access `[0]` on the outer class.

Comment: could you maybe provide the result of your var_dump?

Comment: sure: array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: what is the `$id = $id;` for?

Comment: oh didnt copy paste that right that should be $id = $id[0];

Answer (score 0):

My PHP is a bit rusty and I don't have access to test right now, but don't you need single quotes around the question mark so it goes to SQL quoted?

i.e.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = '?'";
```

or

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, "'" + $_SESSION['username'] + "'");
```

(but not both!)

so that SQL sees 
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = 'MyVal'

instead of 
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = MyVal

which it would interpret as a column name

Comment: No thats not neccesary, within the scope of the method the value returned is correct, i just cant seem to get it outside of the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where the method is called.

You tried this in showinfo.php:

```
$user_id = $id[0];
```

Shouldn't this be...

```
$user_id = getId('someusername', 'somepassword')
```

Or something similar? Sorry this isn't an answer, but I can't comment.

Comment: i'm not sure but i just tested it and it wont work, in fact it ruins the whole page :P